# Change email and password in separate view, how to structure the actions in RESTful app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, restful-url

I have a `User` model with the following attributes:
`name`
`age`
`ìmage`
`email`
`password`

I want the user to edit/update the first three attributes in one view and the other two in another.

Do I break the RESTful pattern if I duplicate the edit/update actions and routes?

What could be a better solution?

Comment: Have a look at `wicked` `gem`: https://github.com/schneems/wicked to implement multi-step edit process.

Comment: No you are not breaking any pattern..

Answer (score 0):

Use one action with extra parameter, like `/user/1/edit` and `/user/1/edit?step=2`.

If you are using some kind of wizard, try to extract it in a separate class:

```
# controller
def update 
  @step == params[:step].presence or Wizard::FIRST_STEP # = 1
  @wizard = Wizard.new(user, @step)
  if @wizard.update(params)
  ...
end

def edit
  ...
  render @wizard.partial # depends on step params 
  ...
```

Comment: It's two completely separate pages, but your idea is cool. I'll try it out and see what comes out of it.